# Simple CSS Grid Items Not Positioning As Expected On Smaller Viewports

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm attempting to use CSS Grid. I created a simple four item grid where I expect the first and last elements to `span` across all `columns`, while the 2nd element will span across only one `column` and start at `column` 1, while the 2nd `column` will span 2 `columns` and end at the last `column`.

I wrote [this codepen](https://codepen.io/technicallynick/pen/abbaEbx?editors=1100) as a simple example of what I'm attempting.

**The Problem**:

When the viewport shrinks down to a small enough size (~800px width), the first and last elements no longer appear in the first column.

The idea here is to *not* use static counts so that the elements can wrap on the page and size according to the user's screen. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```css
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));
      border: 4px solid #BADA55
    }
    .item {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .item1 {
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      background: pink;
    }
    
    .item2 {
      background: deeppink;
      grid-column: span 1;
      width: 300px;
    }
    
    .item3 {
      grid-column: span 2/-1;
      background: blue;
    }
    
    .item4 {
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      background: purple;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the `item3` that is creating an implicit column before the first one since you specified `span 2/-1`. This happen below `800px` because below this value the implicit grid contain only one column whereas `item3` need at least 2.

An idea is to add a media query to fix this issue:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  border: 4px solid #BADA55
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background: pink;
}

.item2 {
  background: deeppink;
  grid-column: span 1;
  width: 300px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: span 2/-1;
  background: blue;
}
@media (max-width:800px) {
.item3 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
 }
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">1</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
  <div class="item item4">4</div>
</div>
```

Here is a simplified example to better illustrate the issue of explicit/implcit grid you are having.

```css
.grid {
  border:2px solid;
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns:200px 200px; /* The explicit grid */
  grid-auto-columns:100px; /* In case of implicit grid this will be used */
  margin:10px;
}
.grid div {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  grid-column:1/-1
}
.grid div.s1 {
  grid-column:span 3/-1;
  background:blue;
}
.grid div.s2 {
  grid-column:span 3;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
<div class="s1"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
<div></div>
<div class="s2"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the above, I defined an explicit grid with 2 columns and one element spanning full width using `grid-column:1/-1`. If we add another item that needs 3 columns you will simply have an extra column and this will belong to the implicit grid. You are having the exact same issue when you fall under 800px and your `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px, 1fr));` generate only one column inside the explicit grid.

Comment: Wouldn't the requirement on `item3` of span2 logically mean that the full grid may never fall below two columns and therefore when it shrinks to being that small, that `item1` and `item4` should always span the full width of the grid? Why does it appear as though they only occupy the 2nd column?

Comment: @technicallynick *mean that the full grid may never fall below two columns and therefore* --> true but there is the implicit grid and the explicit one. When below 800px your template column will only define 1 column as an explicit grid and the item1 and 4 will take full width of that grid then the item 3 will come and say I need 2 column so he will add it's own extra column as an implicit one and at this step we have already placed the 1 and 4 in the explicit one. I know it's a bit tricky, will try to add few examples to illustrate the issue

Comment: @technicallynick added more detail to my answer so you can better understand the issue

Comment: that makes so much sense and perfectly explains the behavior I'm seeing. Thank you so much for this detailed explanation! I think I was wanting 'auto-fit' to calculate the minimum amount of columns. I think the right solution for me is to actually specify that there must be two columns on the container by setting `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr) minmax(400px,1fr))`. That should have the behavior I desire.